# I want a certain div show up/be selected when all other divs aren't showing/selected - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hide

I want to know how I can show a certain div, when all other divs aren't showing anymore. I've tried toggle, but that create a mess. I've used Hide, but after it is hidden it don't show anymore. I recommend you to watch my fiddle then you'll know what I mean.

HTML:

```
<div id="clicks">  
    <a class="click" id="showInfo" data-target=".1"><button>1</button></a>
    <a class="click" id="showDataInput" data-target=".2"><button>2</button></a>
    <a class="click" id="showHistory" data-target=".3"><button>3</button></a>
</div>  

<div class="1" style="display: none;">
    1
</div>
<div class="2" style="display: none;">
    2
</div>
<div class="3" style="display: none;">
    3
</div>
<div id="text">
    "I WANT THIS DIV GONE EVERYTIME I LET DIV 1, 2 OR 3 SHOW BY CLICKING THE BUTTONS. BUT SHOW UP AGAIN WHEN 1, 2 OR 3 IS NOT SHOWING/SELECTED"
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $targets = $('.target');
    $('#clicks .click').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
        $targets.not($target).hide()
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73z48jr2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#clicks .click').click(function () {
    $('div.target' + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
    $('#text').css('display', $('div.target:visible').length ? 'none':'')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/73z48jr2/4/)**

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure if you wanted to be able to show multiple numbers simultaneously (which this does), or just one at at time like Karl-André's code does.

Comment: Yes, my first fiddle did show multiple numbers which was incorrect. So i've updated it. But your method works anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple condition :

```
$('#text').toggle(!$targets.is(':visible'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73z48jr2/2/